# Перебор массива (sass/scss)?

Tags: sass, scss

Не могу понять несколько моментов в переборе массивов в `scss`:

1. Как в цикле получить номер ячейки массива? Например если сейчас мы находимся в `item3`, то номер должен быть 3...
2. Как в цикле получить название ячейки (`item3` например)?
3. Как в цикле получить содержимое ячейки (`red` например)?

Как Вы перебрали бы такой массив?

```css
$colors: (
        item1: green,
        item2: orange,
        item3: red,
        item4: blue,
        item5: lime
);

// визуально накидал цикл, чтобы было более нагляднее то, что я хочу узнать...
@for $i from 1 through length($colors)
{
  .test-#{$number-array}-#{$name-array}
  {
    color: #{$value-array};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение:**

```
@each $key, $color in $colors {
    $index: index($colors, $color);
    .test-#{$index}-#{$key} {
        color: $color;
    }
}
```